# Finding strings that are not in DB already

Tags: performance, linq, optimization

I have some bad performance issues in my application. One of the big operations is comparing strings. 
I download a list of strings, approximately 1000 - 10000. These are all unique strings. 
Then I need to check if these strings already exists in the database. 
The linq query that I'm using looks like this:

```
IEnumerable<string> allNewStrings = DownloadAllStrings();

var selection = from a in allNewStrings
                where !(from o in context.Items
                        select o.TheUniqueString).Contains(a)
                select a;
```

Am I doing something wrong or how could I make this process faster preferably with Linq?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You did query the same unique strings 1000 - 10000 times for every element in `allNewStrings`, so it's extremely inefficient.

Try to query unique strings separately in order that it is executed once:

```
IEnumerable<string> allNewStrings = DownloadAllStrings();

var uniqueStrings = from o in context.Items
                    select o.TheUniqueString;

var selection = from a in allNewStrings
                where !uniqueStrings.Contains(a)
                select a;
```

Now you can see that the last query could be written using `Except` which is more efficient for the case of set operators like your example:

```
var selection = allNewStrings.Except(uniqueStrings);
```

Comment: `Except()` will have much better performance than `!Contains()`

Comment: @Magnus: yes, Set operators are more efficient than member test on sequences. I updated the answer to state it more clearly.

Comment: Thanks for this greate solution. My only initial concern with this is it's working nicely now, but what will happen when I have 1 million posts in Items, and need to "download" them all to memory, and then do the compare?

Comment: This approach is still reasonable for a big number of `uniqueStrings` assuming that you have large memory to avoid cache misses.

Answer (score 1):

An alternative solution would be to use a `HashSet`:

```
var set = new HashSet<string>(DownloadAllStrings());
set.ExceptWith(context.Items.Select(s => s.TheUniqueString));
```

The `set` will now contain the the strings that are not in the DB.